# Can't scroll to dynamic element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys I'm having some issues scrolling to a an element that's dynamically created. You click on a search button, AJAX does its thing and updates the content. I have some code to dynamically find the ID and scroll to it. I am able to get the ID but I can't scroll to it. So far I have the code:

```
to_Scroll = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(to_Scroll).offset().top
}, 2000);
```

Which seems to work when I put it in the console with hard coded data. But doing it dynamically yields no results and no errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Below is some code which is done before I animate and scroll to an element:

```
dateChange(blah, blah2, blah3);
to_Scroll = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(to_Scroll).offset().top
    }, 2000);

function dateChange(dateInput, nGuests, vName){
    var promises = [];
    var promise = $.ajax({
          url: "/blah.asp?blah="+blah+"&blah2="+blah2+"&blah3="+blah3,
          dataType:"html",
          success: function(data){
              table.html(data);
          }
        });
    promises.push(promise);

$.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
    $( "#boatContent" ).removeClass( "loading" ); //Everything is done, remove loading gif
    //do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to use ID again from attr you need to add # to it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var to_Scroll = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( '#' + to_Scroll).offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: I have tried that but it's still not working. Before I do this I have a function that is called which has a few AJAX calls and uses 
$.when and $.done which is used to spit the dynamic content. I don't know if there is an underlying issue because of that

Comment: I want to add, doing this through console, it DOES in fact, work!

Comment: @AkiraDawson if you already can get the ID  the code with # should work

Comment: I know it should work, i'm just baffled as to why it isn't working. I have added more code to my question too

Comment: @AkiraDawson try to put this code in ajax success: after table.html(data); and let me know what happen .. before anything what $(this) refer to? to_Scroll = $(this)

Comment: doing tests, that does work but I can't do that because I have many other functions that call and use the ajax call unfortunately. I have done a dodgy and put a setTimeout() around the scroll function which seems to be working. So there may be a timing issue, I don't know

Comment: @AkiraDawson if not you can wrap that code in $(document).ready(function(){...// your code here....});  and leave all your function outside .. answer updated